# .net core on Ubuntu Write File | System.IO.IOException: Permission denied

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ubuntu, .net-core

I created a .net5.0 ubuntu service (ASP.NET Core Web Application) which is hosting a SignalR Client.
This works perfectly.

Now I am trying to read an application specific configuration file.
No matter where I locate the file, I always get an `System.IO.IOException: Permission denied`

I tried the following paths:

```
 - /ush/share/myConfigFile.config
 - ~/.config/myConfigFile.config
 - ~/.myConfigFolder/myConfigFile.config
 - ~/ApplicationFolder/.myConfigFolder/myConfigFile.config
```

The service is running on ubuntu, this is the .service file I use to start the servie

```
[Unit]
Description=Lumin Service in .NET

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/HeliosClock
ExecStart=/usr/share/dotnet/dotnet /home/ubuntu/HeliosClock/HeliosService.dll
User=ubuntu

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The app permission of the running service are the regular Ubuntu User permission.

The file is accessed with the following code:

```
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(myFilePath, FileMode.Open);
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
string line = await reader.ReadLineAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

The service is running on a Raspberry PI 4 with Ubuntu 20.04

Any help why I always get an `System.IO.IOException: Permission denied`
when I want to load a application specific configuration file.

Is there another folder where config files for user specific application are supposed to be stored?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:
I accessed the configuration file within a HosedService.

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
            services.AddHostedService<HeliosServerClient>();
 }
```

When I injected the ConfigurationService via a Singelton into the HostedService I was able to access the home directory.

Changes code to:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
       services.AddSingleton(configureService);
 }
```

and inject in HeliosServerClient:

```
public HeliosServerClient(ConfiguarationService service)
```